# How can one tell whether a given object is an Array or an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typing

Alright, so nothing fancy here, just some JSON:

```
var a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

var o = {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz"};
```

But what happens when we do this?

```
typeof a; // => "object"
```

I'd like it if I could just get that command to say "array".  But I can't.  Is there any way to differentiate?

Comment: Adding anything non-numeric to an array makes it an associative  (object).

Comment: @Nile — No. JavaScript doesn't have anything called an "associative array". Adding a non-numeric value to an array does nothing special. Adding a non-numeric property to an array is (usually) not best practise, but it doesn't make it an object (since it is an object already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the object is an instance of `Array`:

```
var isArray = a instanceof Array;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```
if (a instanceof Array)
```

Keep in mind that all Arrays are Objects (as Object is on Array's prototype chain), so to distinguish between an Array and a not-Array you have to compare to the `Array` constructor,  you can't use the `Object` constructor for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not in a multi `window` environment, you can either check the constructor...

```
var isArray = possiblyAnArray.constructor == Array;
```

...or use `instanceof`...

```
var isArray = possiblyAnArray instanceof Array;
```

These won't work in a multi `window` environment, as the `Array` constructor of a different window will hold a different reference. In that case, you'd need to do it a slower way...

```
var isArray = ({}).toString.call(possiblyAnArray) == "[object Array]";
```

I've seen another method too, which is very easy to implement but not at all guaranteed to strictly tell you what's an `Array` or not.

```
Array.prototype.isArray = true;
var isArray = [].isArray;
```

I don't recommend using that, but it's interesting to see how it works.

Comment: Ooooh, what would count as a multi-window environment?

Comment: @adlwalrus `iframe` is a good example. It's uncommon, but worthwhile knowing, and worth using the latter if writing a generic utility function (if not, make sure you document it that it won't work cross `window`).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would to use duck typing. It's depends on the use case.

If, for instance, you want to count the items in the array, which is not something you can do in the JSON Object, you can try:

```
if (typeof(obj.length) !=="undefined"){ //do whatever}
```

This will give you the option to base your code on the objects attributes, rather than on it's real class, which might be less relevant in some cases.

Comment: *JSON Object*, can you please explain what that is?

Comment: Just object {} or Object . Underline implementation is a plain key value map.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this: is there anything wrong with it?

```
var a = [4,5,6,7];
if(typeof a === object) a.type = "object";
if(a.__proto__ === Array.prototype) a.type = "array";
```

Comment: Yes, `__proto__` is non-standard and not supported at all in IE.

Comment: Really? How is it so widely used/supported then?  Is it on its way to becoming standard?

Comment: No, the standard is [`getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf). It's widely (if you consider not IE widely) supported because Firefox implemented it and other browsers copied it. It's also not a good way to check when othermethods exist that have excellent browser support.

Comment: Oh, alright. Great. What's the standards-based equivalent to assigning a new value to an object's `.__proto__`?

Comment: There is none, and you shouldn't be setting it like that. You can use `Object.create()` to create a new object with its `[[Prototype]]` set to the first argument.

Comment: So: `var myPrototypeObj = { boilerplate: 'foo' }; var instance = Object.create(myPrototypeObj);` ?

Comment: `var p = {a:3}, var o = Object.create(p);` and then `o.getPrototypeOf()` give `>TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getPrototypeOf'`

Comment: You're using it incorrectly. It'd be `Object.getPrototypeOf(o)`.

Comment: Ewww, it's a static method? The nonstandard one is way sexier, don't you think?

Comment: Worth mentioning that `__proto__` is now becoming standardized.